# Как при наведении на кнопку сделать фон светлее?

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать при наведении фон светлее, фон генерируется автоматически любой

Придумал только способ через `opacity`, он меняет все включая то что внутри кнопки текст и т.д.

Как это сделать без `opacity` ?

```css
.btn {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.btn:hover {
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<!-- В style сгенерированный случайным образом фон -->
<button class="btn" style="background: #22b927; color: #fff;">Кнопка с любым фоном</button>
```

Comment: Наверное никак.

Comment: Я предложил 3 варианта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Первый вариант**: Использовать отдельную переменную для background и при :hover изменять его значение через color-mix. Позволяет применять преобразования любой сложности

```css
.btn {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  transition: all .25s;
  background: var(--background)
}
.btn:hover{
  background: color-mix(in srgb, var(--background), white 30%);
}
```

```html
<button 
        class="btn" 
        style="--background: #22b927; color: #fff;">
  Кнопка с любым фоном
</button>
```

**Второй вариант**: Фильтры. Можно применять [любые](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function) (например [hue-rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate)). Чуть более ограниченны в использовании, так как не позволяют достаточно контролировать изменение цвета, однако это гораздо легче.

```css
.btn {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.btn:hover{
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!-- В style сгенерированный случайным образом фон -->
<button class="btn" style="background: #22b927; color: #fff">Кнопка с любым фоном</button>
```

**Третий вариант**: Использовать события. Позволяет вручную задать любой нужный вам цвет, но как по мне - неудобно

```css
.btn {
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 5px 12px;
      transition: all .25s;
}
```

```html
<button 
        class="btn" 
        style="background: #22b927; color: #fff;"
        onmouseover="this.style.background='#ff22ff'"
        onmouseout="this.style.background='#22b927'"
        >Кнопка с любым фоном
</button>
```

Comment: По моему было сказано, что цвет там случайный устанавливается и кажется не контролируется юзером. По этому второй вариант подходит больше, но опять же, он изменяет яркость всей кнопки, а не фона.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Я предполагал, что добавить "--" будет не так сложно, но на всякий случай всё же добавил другие варианты

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что сайт не его допустим.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Да понимаю я, вы меня слышите? специально для этого я привёл другие варианты, не смотря на то, что второй вариант выглядит плохо

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей Спасибо, первый вариант отлично подходит